# Select class nearest clicked button

Tags: jquery

I want to expand the nearest div with the class "divtoexpand" when clicking button1.

How can I achieve this?

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="button1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="divtoexpand"></div>

<div class="test">
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="button1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="divtoexpand"></div>
```

Comment: docs http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.button1').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('div.test').next('div.divtoexpand').slideDown();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sBFL4/4/)**

Comment: How do I solve it if I add a new div between the test div and the divtoexpand?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a more general approach you could try the following:

```
$('.button1').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parents().next('.divtoexpand').slideDown();
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pWvSd/)

Comment: Unless your DOM contains multiple `.divtoexpand` elements, it is will be more efficient to use `.closest()`. `parents()` will search the entire DOM, and return all the results as an array, while closest() will return the first instance it finds.

Answer (score 0):

First I would give your button an ID.  Then you can do a show when the button is clicked:

```
 <div class="test">
     <div class="menu">
         <div class="button1" id="foo"></div>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="divtoexpand" id="bar"></div>

 <script>
   $("#foo").click(function(){
     $("#bar").show()   
   });  
 </script>
```